# Chromium automation

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, automation

I know a cursory Google search returns several apparently useful add-ons, but I've yet to find something specific.

My problem is this: I keep several screens running a flash player window on fullscreen in different locations. Every so often the connection times out, or some network error produces a black screen. Easily fixed by a reload command. But that reload produces the original webpage, not the player in fullscreen. I can time it at eight-hour intervals, but I need a way to automate both that command and the left mouse click on the fullscreen button right afterward.

Is there an inbuilt Chrome function for it, or some add-on I've yet to find that doesn't require a master's degree to configure?

If not, I figure I could resort to Python, just don't have the time to write it properly.

Comment: You could take a look at [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#purpose), but you'll need to write some code to make it work.

Comment: Seems more and more likely. Do you reckon it'll integrate well with a time module for task scheduelling?

Comment: @[Alex 196418](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10883309/alex-196418) Sure, in Python you could use the built-in `time` module to control the intervals and `PyAutoGUI` for automating the keys and clicks you need, i.e. a double-click to switch back to fullscreen.